# 360 live stitched local camera feed at lowest latency + Unity / iOS / Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, live-streaming, 360-virtual-reality

I'm looking for recommendations on hardware and software to render a live stitched feed from a local 360 camera in Unity (alternatively native iOS or Android) at **absolute minimum latency**.

There is high flexibility regarding the hardware and setup. It can be a mobile or a desktop app. Can be any reasonably priced 360 camera. It can be a wired connection or WiFi direct. The only thing that matters is to have access to the stitched live video feed in a custom app (SDK?) and be able to render it at minimal latency (ideally less than 200ms).

Please can you recommend a specific camera model that will be best for the above and can you please share some hints for how to access its stitched feed programmatically?

Thanks!