# 360 camera live video texture Unity access

Tags: video, unity-game-engine, camera, live-streaming, 360-virtual-reality

I am looking for a 360 camera that will allow me to access its stitched unwrapped video texture live (as a live preview) in Unity. It can be a mobile or a desktop solution. Also wired connection is fine. Please can anyone recommend a camera model that will let me do it?

Thank you

Comment: Please read the help center. This question is considered off topic for Stack Overflow since we don't suggest off site resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Theta360* camera can capture 360 images for your VR app. This [page](http://theta360.guide/community-document/community.html) describes how to display images from it in Unity with a custom shader.

You can use `WWW` and `json` to get `Image` from it through Wifi. [Here](https://github.com/theta360developers/ThetaWifiStreaming/blob/master/Assets/ThetaStreaming/ThetaWifiStreaming.cs) is a full working example of how to do that. You can obtain the whole project [here](https://github.com/theta360developers/ThetaWifiStreaming).

In terms of performance or latency like you mentioned in your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40405425/3785314) post, you should replace `WWW` with `UnityWebRequest` then implement [`DownloadHandlerScript`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html). This will make everything run smoothly especially when you want to stream the images continuously instead of taking snapshots.